# Describe table while table is highly in use in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using java sdk to access dynamo db. Just want some suggestion related to dynamo db describe table.

is it recommended to use describe table while table is in highly use for other read and write operation in dynamo db. Any reference link would be help in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DescribeTable is a [control plane API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.API.html#HowItWorks.API.ControlPlane), and does not consume capacity from your table. So calling DescribeTable API or any other control plane API will not impact any production traffic for data plane (read/write) operations on your table.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have gone through the control plane api call documentation but there its not mentioned that it will not consume the capacity of table and not impact traffic performance. Can you please provide me some reference link for it.

Comment: I don't believe its documented, you can provide feedback on the docs if you believe it should exist there. For now, I can assure you that you can take my word for it.